# How does R do exact wilcox rank sum tests?

Tags: r, testing, sum, rank

I read the documentation in R for `wilcox.test()` and want to determine:

1. How R computes `wilcox.test()`
2. The docs say that when the number of samples is small, it does the test exactly (instead of using a normal approximation) -- what tables does it use to do this exactly?

Comment: There are no tables involved. You can type `wilcox.test`, `methods("wilcox.test")`, `getAnywhere("wilcox.test.default")` to have a look for yourself at just how `wilcox.test` does what it does!

Comment: when i do this, it just gives me this

Comment: > wilcox.test()
Error in wilcox.test.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
> methods("wilcox.test")
[1] wilcox.test.default* wilcox.test.formula*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
> methods("wilcox.test.default")
Error in methods("wilcox.test.default") : 
  no function 'wilcox.test.default' is visible
> wilcox.test
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("wilcox.test")
<bytecode: 0x1033f62a0>
<environment: namespace:stats>

Comment: `wilcox.test.default` is "hidden" in the **stats** package's namespace. That's why you need to do  `getAnywhere("wilcox.test.default")` (or `stats:::wilcox.test.default`) to view it.

Comment: when you start to dig into `stats:::wilcox.test.default`, you will discover that it calls `pwilcox`. Good news: `?pwilcox` gives a brief description of how the calculation is done.  Bad news: if you want to see *exactly* what's going on you will need to look here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/wilcox.c

Answer (score 0):

wilcox.test.default is "hidden" in the stats package's namespace.

That's why you need to do `getAnywhere("wilcox.test.default")` or `stats:::wilcox.test.default` to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Package exactRankTests can do exact wilcox rank sum tests.